# Unable to remove characters from a SQL string

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a SQL table with a number of fields. In any of the text fields there are repeated characters to the right of the string I am interested in such as below:

> 'AAA..........................' -- Unfortunately stacked overflow is trimming the characters (Ironic?) in the post so I have replaced them with '.' to try and give an impression.

When I run the sql below, the hidden characters appear to be spaces:

```
SELECT ASCII(RIGHT(EXCHANGE, 1)) FROM T_TMP_INS -- Returns 32
```

If I run the following:

```
SELECT REPLACE(FIELD, CHAR(32), '@') FROM TABLE1
```

The result is:

> AAA@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@

So I assumed I could just use an update to remove the space character as such:

```
UPDATE TABLE1 SET FIELD = REPLACE(FIELD, CHAR(32), '')
```

But the update doesn't change the field what so ever.

Is there a reason I am missing as to why the select is recognising and replaces the erroneous characters and the update statement isn't?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: How is the column defined? I suppose it is either CHAR or NCHAR instead of VARCHAR or NVARCHAR, which have no length information and pad the content with spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the field is declared as e.g. `char(10)` then it will *always* contain 10 characters, with spaces added at the end to make up for shorter strings.

If you want to declare a column as capable of storing strings *up to* 10 characters long, but don't want padding for shorter values, it should be declared as `varchar(10)`. (Similarly, `nchar` and `nvarchar`).

(If you're unable to change the column declarations and just need to fix it during retrieval, then you should first `CAST` or `CONVERT` to the `varchar`/`nvarchar` form and *then* trim the end with `RTRIM`)

---

You could also be tempted to adjust the [`ANSI_PADDING`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-ansi-padding-transact-sql) settings to change this behaviour. I'd suggest not to do this though - this *is* the standard behaviour for any SQL database system and so I'd recommend working with that rather than using a non-standard product-specific work around.

Comment: This makes perfect sense. I didn't understand the differences between char and varchar until this response. Just dropped my table and recreated it with varchar. Loaded data and looks fine now thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the characters are spaces you can use `RTRIM(FIELD)` to trim them.

If there are leading spaces too, you can use `LTRIM(RTRIM(FIELD))`.

Comment: As with the replace, the RTRIM and LTRIM functions only work with the SELECT. Using UPDATE they no longer work

Comment: Then check the type of the column as @Damien_The_Unbeliever mentioned.